# IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I keep getting a Fatal java.lang.IllegalStateException error when I start up my app and I'm not sure why.  Basically all I'm trying to do is return the running processes and tasks every 10 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler h = new Handler();
    public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    int s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Checker();
    }

    public void Checker() {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.post(check);
    }

    Runnable check = new Runnable() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        public void run() {
            Processes(am);
            Tasks(am);
            h.postAtTime(check, 10000);
        }
    };

    public void Processes(ActivityManager am) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        s = l.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Process:  " + l.get(i).processName);
        }
    }

    public void Tasks(ActivityManager am) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> l = am.getRunningTasks(1000);
        s = l.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            // .baseActivity returns the process that started the Task
            Log.d(TAG, "Task:  " + l.get(i).baseActivity.getPackageName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here are my logs:

```
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidside/com.example.androidside.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4463)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.example.androidside.MainActivity$1.<init>(MainActivity.java:54)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.example.androidside.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:53)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
12-18 08:03:53.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to change your code**

```
Handler h ;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            h = new Handler();
            Checker();
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work, still getting the same exception, thanks for trying though.

Comment: Well, when I did what you suggested with the Handler AND the Activity Manager, it worked then.

Answer (score 0):

First try to initialize variables when you need them:

```
private Handler h;
private Runnable check;

public void Checker() {
    check = new Runnable() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        public void run() {
            Processes(am);
            Tasks(am);
            h.postAtTime(check, 10000);
        }
    };
    h = new Handler();
    h.post(check);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 
    Checker();
}
```

Second, try to choose variable names which actually say something about what it is. For example, change `l` in `taskList`, `s` in `listSize`, and `h` in `handler`. Also, method names do NOT start with a capital.